# in-place upgrade has been disabled in Windows Server 2019 Core to Window Server 2022 Core

Tags: windows-server-2019, upgrade, windows-server-core, windows-server-2022

ITNOA

Hi,

I have a licensed media, and I can in-place upgrade from Windows Server 2019 Data Center [Desktop Experience] to Windows Server 2022 Data Center [Desktop Experience].

But When I want to in-place upgrade from Windows Server 2019 Data Center Core to Windows Server 2022 Data Center Core, Keep files, settings, and apps option is disable. **How to resolve this issue?**

[image]

My current Windows Server 2019 core details is in below

```
Get-ComputerInfo -Property WindowsProductName,WindowsBuildLabEx,WindowsEditionID

WindowsProductName        WindowsBuildLabEx                       WindowsEditionId
------------------        -----------------                       ----------------
Windows Server Datacenter 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406 ServerDatacenterACor
```

All of my roles installed on server core is

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object {$_. installstate -eq "installed"} | Format-List Name,Installstate | more

Name         : AD-Domain-Services
InstallState : Installed

Name         : DNS
InstallState : Installed

Name         : FileAndStorage-Services
InstallState : Installed

Name         : File-Services
InstallState : Installed

Name         : FS-FileServer
InstallState : Installed

Name         : Storage-Services
InstallState : Installed

Name         : NET-Framework-Features
InstallState : Installed

Name         : NET-Framework-Core
InstallState : Installed

Name         : NET-Framework-45-Features
InstallState : Installed

Name         : NET-Framework-45-Core
InstallState : Installed

Name         : NET-WCF-Services45
InstallState : Installed

Name         : NET-WCF-TCP-PortSharing45
InstallState : Installed

Name         : Containers
InstallState : Installed

Name         : GPMC
InstallState : Installed

Name         : RSAT
InstallState : Installed

Name         : RSAT-Feature-Tools
InstallState : Installed

Name         : RSAT-System-Insights
InstallState : Installed

Name         : RSAT-Role-Tools
InstallState : Installed

Name         : RSAT-AD-Tools
InstallState : Installed

Name         : RSAT-AD-PowerShell
InstallState : Installed

Name         : RSAT-DNS-Server
InstallState : Installed

Name         : System-DataArchiver
InstallState : Installed

Name         : System-Insights
InstallState : Installed

Name         : Windows-Defender
InstallState : Installed

Name         : PowerShellRoot
InstallState : Installed

Name         : PowerShell
InstallState : Installed

Name         : PowerShell-V2
InstallState : Installed

Name         : WoW64-Support
InstallState : Installed
```

And the edition of my Windows Core server is

```
DISM /Online Get-CurrentEdition

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Image Version: 10.0.19042.1889

Current edition is:

Current Edition : ServerDatacenterACor

The operation completed successfully.
```

My hotfixes installed on my server is like below

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wmic qfe get hotfixid,installedon
HotFixID   InstalledOn
KB5015730  12/9/2022
KB4534170  4/20/2020
KB4545706  4/20/2020
KB4562830  3/11/2021
KB5016616  12/9/2022
KB5007273  12/30/2021
KB5011352  3/19/2022
KB5015895  12/9/2022
KB5003242  5/21/2021
```

my `dcdiag` command output is like below

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = WS2019CORE-MAIN
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WS2019CORE-MAIN
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\WS2019CORE-MAIN
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x00000022
            Time Generated: 12/13/2022   11:08:42
            Event String:
            The time service has detected that the system time needs to be  changed by 0 seconds. The time service will not change the system time by more than 172800 seconds. Verify that your time and time zone are correct, and that the time source VM IC Time Synchronization Provider is working properly.
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN failed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... WS2019CORE-MAIN passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : test
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... test passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... test passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : test.local
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... test.local passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... test.local passed test Intersite
```

**Update**

I create question in microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1123512/in-place-upgrade-disable-in-windows-server-core-20 but I cannot find my solution yet.

Thanks

Comment: ServerDatacenterACor may be the semi-annual channel. I don't believe that will work here. Also the semi annual channel is now gone for Windows Server 2022. It would help to have the output of `wmic qfe get hotfixid,installedon` to know more.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/servicing-channels-comparison

Comment: @GregAskew I update my question and provide your requested information, thanks for attention :)

Comment: How to resolve `The time service has detected that the system time needs to be  changed by 0 seconds. The time service will not change the system time by more than 172800 seconds. Verify that your time and time zone are correct, and that the time source VM IC Time Synchronization Provider is working properly.`?

Comment: As I suspected, this was the semi-annual channel, so it looks like there isn't an upgrade path. Also this release of Windows Server (20H2) was end of life four months ago. These short-lived releases were not intended for roles such as a domain controller. Probably a good idea to stay with mainstream Windows. Promote another domain controller and throw this one away.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to upgrade using an Evaluation version of the Windows Server ISO freely available from Microsoft, but it wouldn't let me keep files and settings.

When I used a standard edition ISO it did work.

The lesson here seems to be that it does matter exactly which version of the installer you're trying to use.

Answer (score -1):

Chose the Windows Upgrade version that you want with (Desktop Experience) selected as opposed to just Windows 20222 Standard. That fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I tried it, but it is not resolve my problem